# Python stop iterate after line is found in list

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to search all lines between "from here" and "!" but code also keep running once it found !.

**Below lines I am trying to process:**

file started here

few lines

from here

some other lines here

few more lines

!

!

!

something here as well

!

Code below give me output as:

start

some other lines here

few more lines

!

!

!something here as well

!

**Code:**

```
def recursion(start,end):

log = False
buffer=""
for line in lines:
    if re.search(start,lines):
        buffer = line
        log = True
    elif re.search(end,lines):

        buffer += lines
        log = False
    elif log:
        buffer += lines


return buffer

file1=open('test.txt','w')
op1=recursion('from here','!')

file1.writelines(op1)
```

Regards
Mahesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A break needs to be added in the else clause, when the end string is found. Also, 'line' and not 'lines' should be appended to buffer.

Here's the fixed version:

```
def recursion(start, end):
  log = False
  buffer=""

  for line in lines.split('\n'):
    if start in line:
      buffer = line + '\n'
      log = True
    elif end in line:
      buffer += line
      log = False
      break
    elif log:
      buffer += line + '\n'
  return buffer
```

In an iterative approach, simple string search functions should help. re shouldn't be needed.

Here's a one-liner re based implementation:

```
def recursion(start,end):
    return re.findall('(from here.*?!)', lines, re.DOTALL)[0]
```

**Output**

```
$ cat test.txt
cat: test.txt: No such file or directory
$ 

$ cat bar.py
import re
lines = """
file started here
few lines
from here
some other lines here
few more lines
!
!
!
something here as well
!
Code below give me output as:
start
some other lines here
few more lines
!
!
!something here as well
!
"""

def recursion(start,end):
  return re.findall('(from here.*?!)', lines, re.DOTALL)[0]

file1=open('test.txt','w')
op1=recursion('from here','!')
file1.writelines(op1)
$ 

$ python bar.py
$ 

$ cat test.txt
from here
some other lines here
few more lines
!$
```

Comment: Tried your first code it give me unexpected outputr because my file contain '!' even before 'from here'. The generated file only having '!' because it executed break during first input of '!'. Any input ?

Comment: You may modify the elif clause to say: if log and end in line: